# CONVERT or CAST in db2, how to convert a column from char to decimal

Tags: casting, char, db2, decimal, converters

I am trying to connect two columns togheter like.

```
select cast(user as decimal) from trans where user <> date
```

date is a DECIMAL
user is a CHAR

but I get a error:  data mapping conversion error.

I even tried:

```
select  CAST(date AS VARCHAR(10)) from trans where date <> user
```

this gives me a error aswell.

I´m trying to match the users with the date so I get a result that shows all the users who havethe same date.

have someone any idea what I can do to aschive this?

[SAMPLE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFRQW.jpg)

Comment: Can you specify the error for date conversion as well

Comment: Can you provide any sample of data you get your error on?

Comment: I havent provide any sample becuse I havent achived any result yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your user variable has some data which don't Qualify as **Decimal**. 
Check you are not using the converting variable in Order by Clause.

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/sqlp/rbafyretrievalerrors.htm) is explanation for the error.

Comment: You got a point. Probobly the date dont qualify becuse lauser contains characters like "I567ABCD" but it must be some way to join the dates with user, but I dont get it how to convert or cast. The error message for both tries is:

Error during execution of SQLError: java.sql.SQLexception; [SQL802]
Data conversion or data mapping error.

Comment: Can you give table structure and sample output data to help you with your Query

Comment: The structure is:

LAUSER CHAR 10
LADATU DECIMAL 8
LAART CHAR 15
FROM TRLLA00


I uploaded the picture of sample on my first question, let me know how you solve this issue. I´m trying to learn during the time I ask questions :)

Comment: What is the current data in trans table please share the screenshot for that also

Comment: I´m sorry, but I dont know what you mean, du mean "DATA" like "DECIMAL" and "INTEGER", I havent manage to get any data yet. I would be very glad if you could be more specific what "DATA" menas, this would help me further with my learning in db2